# Nativescript how to write HTML in typescript like document.write()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nativescript

basically I want to generate a specific number of labels at different row/col positions based on user input but I cannot find anywhere that tells how to write to the .component.html document from the .component.ts document.  I basically want to use something like document.write() but for nativescript.

Comment: This isn't even a proper approach in the browser

Comment: Can you add some details like what you want to write, where, is it on some event..

Comment: NativeScript is not Browser, it doesn't support DOM or Browser dependent JS APIs. You would use programatically create and inject Views, but since Angular supports dynamic templating you can take advantage of that.

Answer (score 0):

Use [interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#interpolation-and-template-expressions) (denoted by `{{...}}`) to insert data from component in template:

Component:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  labels = [
    {
      id: '1',
      name: '',
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      name: '',
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      name: '',
    },
  ];

  public onKey(event: any) {
    for (const label of this.labels) {
      label.name = event.target.value;
    }
  }
}
```

Template (HTML):

```
<div class="divTable">
  <div class="divTableBody">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let label of labels">
      <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell">{{ label.id }}</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">{{ label.name }}</div>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>

<p>Type here:</p>
<input (keyup)="onKey($event)">
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-meyfr6)